# Testing annotation processor with compile-testing

Tags: java, annotation-processing

I'm using Google's [compile-testing](https://github.com/google/compile-testing) library to test my annotation processor. My test is failing saying the generated resource can't be found. I'd like to check what's happening, but I can't get the library to tell me either the compiler output (containing logs from my processor) or the files it did generate. Is it possible to access those things?

Comment: I reported an issue about this: https://github.com/google/compile-testing/issues/75

Comment: I have the same problem, did any one find a solution to this?